# How to debug plugins with GDB in ROS

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all !

I am still a novice in debugging. I ran into the problem of writing my own global planner plugin and keeps popping out error, such as the one found on [my other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/224971/cannot-load-ompl-global-planner-plugin/), or the one below not even giving any explicit complain upon crashing:

> [move_base-1] process has died [pid 10503, exit code -11 (...)]

I managed to open an external GDB window for debugging following the instruction [on this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB). At this point it is pretty clear how to debug a certain node, but then my question is, since what I want is to debug a plugin (not the way presented with [this question ,duh](http://answers.ros.org/question/148361/debug-with-gdb-a-ros-plugins-for-gazebo/) !!), what should the proper way to do so with GDB? Or do I need to make the plugin as a certain node to better debug it ? Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225402/how-to-debug-plugins-with-gdb-in-ros/) by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't run a plugin by itself in gdb; you need to run it as part of a node.

The easiest way to go about this is to run the node which loads your plugin in gdb; in this case that would be move_base. Just edit the launch file which runs move_base to run it inside of gdb.

Depending on the node and the failure case, you may get more output by adding the `output="screen"` option in your launch file as well.

As a side node, negative exit codes (like -11) indicate the signal that caused your program to exit; signal 11 is segfault. The signal numbers are standardized for all Linux, OSX and POSIX systems, and are widely documented; for example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-02-15**:
Hi ahendrix,

Your answer is truly awesome! I've never heard of such a documentation on Linux signal and it is very useful!
I already added output="screen" before posting this question, so I guess the best way to debug is using ROS_DEBUG_STREAM or write an extra int main to run it as a node. Agree?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-15**:
If you already have `output="screen"`, the next step is to run your node in a debugger: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

**Comment by [Megacephalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23714/megacephalo/) on 2016-04-09**:
Hi, ahendrix!
Thank you ! I will try debugging this way. Thank you :) !

**Comment by [MartinS](https://answers.ros.org/users/33225/martins/) on 2018-01-09**:
Sure, but how do you actually step into the source code of a plugin once you are running the node?  GDB won't follow the pointer.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-01-10**:
@MartinS: that is better asked in a new question, and it looks like you've already done it: https://answers.ros.org/question/279324/how-do-you-step-into-plugins-with-gdb/